# Linking List via unique Number

Tags: unique, related-list

I have two Custom lists "Master" & "Scoring", I want a column within my "Scoring" list called "Total Score" to automatically populate a column in my Master list called "Issue Scoring" using the Issue ID in each list as a link.. Is this possible and how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a one-to-one relationship (i.e. one scoring entry for each master entry) it is easy. A workflow running on scoring item changes can update master list by looking up with Issue ID.

If there are multiple entries on Scoring list that needs to be summed, you then need to create a workflow with a loop on item change. Slightly more complicated, following link explains how to do it:

[Loop Through SP Custom List Items](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/313769/loop-through-sharepoint-custom-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: It is a one-to-one relationship

Comment: Simpler then. A SPD 2013 workflow action running on item creation change with an Update Item statement targeting Master list and referencing the Issue ID.

Comment: Would that be the same for SPD 2010? We have SP 2013 but the workflows available  to us are 2010

Comment: Indeed, Update Item works similarly in SPD 2010.

Comment: Can you provide any links web video's that walk through setting up a one to one relationship as I can't seem to get this to work. This is first workflow I've created in  designer and I'm completely lost.

Comment: 1. Create a new workflow (2010 in your case). SPD, workflows, select List Workflow from top left, select Scoring list.

Comment: 1. Create a new workflow (2010 in your case). SPD, workflows, select List Workflow from top left, select Scoring list. Give it a name and select 2010.
2. Within Step1 section which comes by default, type update and press enter.
3. Click this list and select Master list from the drop down. Click add and select Issue Score for the first field, and Current Item: Total Score for the second field. Towards the bottom, select Issue ID for the Field field, and select Current Item: Issue ID for the value. 
4. Click Ok.

Comment: 5. Click workflow name above the designer, just before where it says text-based designer to go back to main screen. Under start options select create and change. 6. Click Publish Workflow button, wait until for it to finish before testing. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will give this a bash ... Thanks so much for your time

Comment: Thanks again for your help Charles I now have a fully operational workflow which updates my master list .